# Create div as image

Tags: css, html

I want to know if it would be possible to create a div in html and css as the picture, if possible, how could it?

[image: -]

I have this: http://jsbin.com/kokuc/1/edit

I can set the size of each side? so we can make bigger the underside

Comment: Maybe setting a background image on the div?

Comment: What does "As I can do more pixelated?" mean?

Comment: @j08691 I think it's a joke... but maybe not

Comment: You mean you want corners to have edges "8-bit" look, not smooth and round?

Comment: I think Yuriy Galanter is correct. I think openalfred wants pixelated corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this era, you won't be able to get that type of border (pixelated) on an element.

So the ideal way of doing such thing would be the usage of a background-image for the div.

```
div {
  background-image: url('../link/to/image.png');
}
```

Why? Because that type of 8-bit borders and output is outdated now. No OS or Web Browser would allow you to do that as default, and using CSS it would be really hard if you can even manage to do so. Thus leaving the option of using `background-image` to set this sort of border and all other stuff.

Comment: I can understand that you can not make it pixelated, but you can add that black shadow?

Comment: Nope that is also pixelated, so it's not gonna work either! @openalfred

Comment: I'm doing as you say, with a picture, I work well with the image uploaded to imgur.com, but with the image on my computer does not work - see this: http://i.imgur.com/LdudvEv.png

Comment: I am sorry you are experiencing this trouble, can you please tell me what is not going good? @openalfred .. I think that should work..Try reloading the page of try using it as: `background-image: url('../images/divdrop.png');`

Comment: if, I ask another guy and I said, first I exit the folder 'CSS' and then if enter 'images', thanks! ('../images/divdrop.png')

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is rather simple to do.

You can use an image in the css `background` property.  Use this code as an example:

```
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pGzLkoF.png);
```

You'll need to resize the div to fit the picture.  You can also save the picture into a file directory, then put the path to the file inside of `url()` instead of the web url you posted.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned; the pixelated corners would have to be from a background image.

But the colors and rounded corners can of course be pure web code.

*Note: Not exact. But should easily get you there.*

```
#cooldiv { 
   border:2px solid #a1a1a1; 
   padding:10px 40px; 
   background-image: url('transparent.png');
   width:300px;
   border-radius:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... This is possible with pure css but I would not suggest it since it is not very practical.

The best option, as stated, would be to use a `background-image`. If you need somethign to be responsive on every size and want to have some flexibility then I would suggest an `SVG` image (scalable vector graphic) because this can be sized to any screen size. SVG also have IE8<= which should be something to take into consideration.

Here is how I accomplished this,

html:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="frame-1">
        <div class="top-1"></div>
        <div class="middle-1"></div>
        <div class="bottom-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame-2">
        <div class="top-2"></div>
        <div class="middle-2"></div>
        <div class="bottom-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="frame-3">
        <div class="top-3"></div>
        <div class="middle-3"></div>
        <div class="bottom-3"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Here is some text or whatever that will go in this abomination.</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.frame {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.frame p {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}

.frame-1 {
    width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
}

.top-1, .middle-1, .bottom-1 {
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
}

.top-1 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    left: 5%;
}

.middle-1 {
    width: 96%;
    height: 280px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
}

.bottom-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    top: 20px;
}

.frame-2 {
    width: 570px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}

.top-2, .middle-2, .bottom-2 {
    background: rgb(46, 170, 228);
    position: absolute;
}

.top-2 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 270px;
    left: 5%;
}

.middle-2 {
    width: 96%;
    height: 250px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
}

.bottom-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 230px;
    top: 20px;
}

.frame-3 {
    width: 540px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}

.top-3, .middle-3, .bottom-3 {
    background: rgb(147, 200, 235);
    position: absolute;
}

.top-3 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 240px;
    left: 5%;
}

.middle-3 {
    width: 96%;
    height: 220px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 2%;
}

.bottom-3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Finally, a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88zju/3/)

Fiddle with the shadow not perfectly even: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88zju/4/)

Comment: is very difficult to achieve the identical image 'div', but excellent help, thanks! decided to use background image for div

Comment: No problem, that was a good decision mate and best of luck!